# Are Config Sets stored on the same nodes as the cores that use them

Tags: solr

[The page explaining Config Sets](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/config-sets.html)  mentions this:

> On a multicore Solr instance, you may find that you want to share
>   configuration between a number of different cores. You can achieve
>   this using named configsets, which are essentially shared
>   configuration directories stored under a configurable configset base
>   directory.

But where are these `configsets` actually stored. Are they placed on the same nodes as the cores? Or are they placed in some kind of master node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you're referring to is about *multicore* installations. These are not cloud or cluster installations, and do only have a single node (in very old version of Solr there was only a single core supported, but after a while multicore installations became available). There is nothing to distribute as there is only a single node.

For Solr Cloud / cluster installations, the configsets are stored in Zookeeper like all other configuration and the cluster state.